# How to sign EXE in Linux with SHA256?

Tags: linux, mono, exe

I need to be able to sign a EXE in Linux. Following the directions listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Signing_an_executable_with_Authenticode, I was able to get it done using Mono. However, I'm running into problems -- apparently Mono's signcode only supports md5 and sha1 hash algorithm. I'm trying to sign using sha256. Anyone know how I can get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a Delphi question. Once it's a compiled EXE, anything you do with that EXE is in no way related to Delphi.

Comment: @JerryDodge I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find out how to do this with Mono's signcode but this can be done using https://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/files/osslsigncode/ -- use -h sha2 parameter when signing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mono documenation following algorithms are supported:
[`sha1 | md5 | sha2 | sha256 | sha384 | sha512`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/d75c142a4646af45f680cd90cafe05843d1d5945/man/signcode.1#L30)

So the adjusted example from Mozilla would look like this:

````
signcode \
 -spc authenticode.spc \
 -v authenticode.pvk \
 -a sha256 -$ commercial \
 -n My\ Application \
 -i http://www.example.com/ \
 -t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll \
 -tr 10 \
 MyApp.exe```
````